# Where can I get a touch event with phase UITouchPhaseStationary?

Tags: iphone

In these methods, I get corresponding phases:
touchesBegan:withEvent: UITouchPhaseBegan,
touchesMoved:withEvent: UITouchPhaseMoved,
touchesEnded:withEvent: UITouchPhaseEnded,
touchesCancelled:withEvent: UITouchPhaseCancelled.

Where can I get a touch event with this phase: *UITouchPhaseStationary*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assume a touch in the time between 2 `Moved` events as stationary.

(`UITouchPhaseStationary` exists because of multitouch. If one finger moves while the other doesn't, a `Moved` event is still triggered, but the stationary touch will be in the phase `UITouchPhaseStationary`.)

Comment: Do you know this by experiments or some document?

Comment: @yehnan: Documents. I guess most iPhoneOS programming tutorials will talk about this.

Comment: Oh, I know. But tutorials usually mention it in about only one or two sentences. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can.  but iOS *doesn't send* touch stationary finger events.  As @KennyTM said, they actually come in the `allTouches` array of the `UIEvent` object whenever any of the other 4 types of touchevents occur.

```
const char* touchPhaseName[] = {
  "UITouchPhaseBegan",             // whenever a finger touches the surface.
  "UITouchPhaseMoved",             // whenever a finger moves on the surface.
  "UITouchPhaseStationary",        // whenever a finger is touching the surface but hasn't moved since the previous event.
  "UITouchPhaseEnded",             // whenever a finger leaves the surface.
  "UITouchPhaseCancelled"
} ;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  for( UITouch* touch in event.allTouches )
  {
    // event.allTouches INCLUDES the other fingers, some of which may still be stationary
    printf( "Touch id=%d is in phase %s\n", touch, touchPhaseName[touch.phase] ) ;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

More information, for example currently I have 3 fingers down. If one of them moves, then `-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` will triggers but there is **only one touch in `touches`** and that only one touch has a phase of `UITouchPhaseMoved`.

If you want 3 touches of moved, stationary, stationary phases then you need to check `[event allTouches]`. (Has the same `(NSSet<UITouch *> *)` type as `touches`) The `touches` only contains the touch that trigger the callback and thus you never get stationary phase out of `touches` because there is no such callback for stationary (holding still) input.